# Как вызвать принудительный рендер компонента из него самого в React Native

Tags: react-native

Как вызвать принудительный перерендер функционального компонента из него самого? Проблема такая - в компоненте есть кнопка вызывающая модальное окно, в модальном окне есть 2 кнопки которые вызывают переход на разные компоненты через навигатион. Если в следующем компоненте нажать кнопку назад которая вызывает navigation.pop то снова попадаем на компонент где кнопка вызывающая модальное окно. Но, эта кнопка уже не вызывает модальное окно - у неё обработчик меняется САМ на обработчик той кнопки, которая была нажата перед переходом на следующий компонент.

Comment: Покажите код. Скорее всего где то там ошибка и ререндер компонента не спасет(или будет костылем)